# Array return 0 but does not return 1

Tags: laravel

My array is correct and returns 0 but does not return 1 offset

My controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $latestProduct = Product::orderBy('created_at','desc')->limit(10)->get();

    return view('frontend.main.index',compact('latestProduct'));
}
```

My code1 in view:

```
{{$product->photos}}
```

return 1:

```
[
  {
    "id":187,
    "path":"\/images\/16259960581d3132f88b1513030d6e5e15ae3fc483953f40f6_1602671371.jpg",
    "name":"1d3132f88b1513030d6e5e15ae3fc483953f40f6_1602671371.jpg",
    "user_id":16,
    "created_at":"2021-07-11 14:04:18",
    "updated_at":"2021-07-11 14:04:18",
    "pivot":{
      "product_id":12,
      "photo_id":187
    }
  },
  {
    "id":188,
    "path":"\/images\/1625996058be7a0e9bf7866759fa3cea7648b149f589a01040_1607438980.jpg",
    "name":"be7a0e9bf7866759fa3cea7648b149f589a01040_1607438980.jpg",
    "user_id":16,
    "created_at":"2021-07-11 14:04:18",
    "updated_at":"2021-07-11 14:04:18",
    "pivot":{
      "product_id":12,
      "photo_id":188
    }
  },
  {
    "id":189,
    "path":"\/images\/1625996058cafe874fb584fd25b1f20e805fec0a36384a5058_1606735174.jpg",
    "name":"cafe874fb584fd25b1f20e805fec0a36384a5058_1606735174.jpg",
    "user_id":16,
    "created_at":"2021-07-11 14:04:18",
    "updated_at":"2021-07-11 14:04:18",
    "pivot":{
      "product_id":12,
      "photo_id":189
    }
  }
]
```

My code2 in view:

```
{{$product->photos[0]}}
```

return 1:

```
{
  "id":197,
  "path":"\/images\/1625997651116701242.jpg",
  "name":"116701242.jpg",
  "user_id":16,
  "created_at":"2021-07-11 14:30:51",
  "updated_at":"2021-07-11 14:30:51",
  "pivot":{
    "product_id":14,
    "photo_id":197
  }
}
```

My code 3 :

```
{{$product->photos[1]}}
```

return 3 :

```
Undefined offset: 1 (View: xxxx\index.blade.php)
```

I want code 3, please help to solve it

Thanks

Comment: Product with id=12 has 3 photos. Product with id=14 has only 1. What is the problem?

Comment: maybe a product has 1 or more photos

Comment: Then loop over them instead of using arbitrary indexes. (`@foreach($product->photos as $photo) {{ $photo }} @endforeach`)

Comment: I want to access path for image src

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem
for object empty return this error so i write this code

```
 @if(!empty($product->photos[1]->path))
```

========================================================================

Answer (score -1):

```xml
<ul>
  @foreach ($product->photos as $photo)
    <li>{{ $photo->path }}</li>
  @endforeach
</ul>
```